# Wrap Text in JSF Page

Tags: jsf

I have a JSF page with xhtml and java file.

In my xhtml page, I use this to display data:

```
<h:outputText style="font-weight: bold;white-space: pre" value="Failing Program:" />
<h:outputText style="" value="#{registerData.fp}"   styleClass="courierFont"/>
```

And in my java file, I read the content from a text file and substring it as:

```
fp = genRegStr.substring(998,1058);
```

It displays the output as:

[image]

The gap between failing program and content is needed and is my css. But is there a way to erradicate the space between the

```
Z2S0    OBJ-z2s0sx          +000011BC  TRC-COA4 LOADSET-BASE
```

I tried the replaceAll function in java but doesnt seem to work. Any other way using css or even java? All i need is to remove extra spaces and leave only one space inbetween the content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `trim()` with `replaceAll(" +", " ")` as following:

```
String before = "Z2S0    OBJ-z2s0sx          +000011BC  TRC-COA4 LOADSET-BASE";     
String after = before.trim().replaceAll(" +", " ");
```

`trim()` will truncate leading and trailing spaces, while `replacAll()` with this expression `" +"` will replace multiple spaces present in the string with single space.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`String.trim()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim()) when retrieving the string from the file:

> Returns a copy of the string, with leading and trailing whitespace omitted.

Change

```
fp = genRegStr.substring(998,1058);
```

By

```
fp = genRegStr.substring(998,1058).trim();
```